# Change first $field in PHP to a link?

Tags: php

Hey i have built a basic database query script that displays rows for me in a table.
I would like to somehow take the first $field from the row (NOT ID) and change it to a link?
How would that be possible:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

if (isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) 
{
    echo "<tr ".$tr_class.">\n";
    foreach ($row as $field=>$value) {  
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "<td><a href='process_edit.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='process_delete.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

I am trying to create it so when the user clicks on the link they will be taken to a page that shows more information :)
Alex

Comment: change **id** to the field you want

Comment: If (for some reason) you don't know the field name after `id`, you could change `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysql_fetch_array` and use the index, such as, `$row[1]`, but `$row['id']` will still work, too.

Comment: i would worry if you don't know the db field names

Comment: I know the field names XD, but since i'm using the loop with $value can i somehow select the 2nd $value and change to Link?

Comment: fixed indentation - extra spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna the first field in your looping, use a variable to initialize your column.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
    echo "<tr ".$tr_class.">\n";
    $a=0;
    foreach ($row as $field=>$value) {  
        echo $a==0?"<td><a href='detail.php?id=".$row["id"]."'>Detail</a></td>":"<td>".$value."</td>";
        $a++;
    }
    echo "<td><a href='process_edit.php?id=".$row["id"]."'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='process_delete.php?id=".$row["id"]."'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

or you can use your ID.

```
foreach ($row as $field=>$value) {  
    echo $field=="id"?"<td><a href='detail.php?id=".$value."'>Detail</a></td>":"<td>".$value."</td>";
    $a++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate i managed to get it working like i wanted using the first option. the second one didnt work though :) Thanks again!